# How do i access data in localStorage that was created in a cordova/phonegap app in my react native version of the app?

Tags: cordova, react-native, local-storage

I am migrating a cordova app to react native and need to access the localstorage to persist login when we update the app.

How do i access the window.localStorage from my old app in my updated version of the app?

I am using react-native 0.60.5 i have Async Storage but that doesnt show the keys i need/should have.

I have tried to get this package installed but im not sure if its compatible with the latest version of react native.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-webkit-localstorage-reader

I get a build error after following all the steps.

/react-native/React/Base/RCTBridgeModule.h:10:9: 'React/RCTDefines.h' file not found

Comment: please show the errors

Comment: ive updated the post to show the error

Comment: Did you ever find a working solution to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this problem too, for me what worked is this:

Before any app loading I will check if the old data storage is migrated ( RN LocalStorage value f.ex: **WEBVIEW_LOCAL_STORAGE_MIGRATED** ) if not, I will present a WebView screen that has in itself an inject JS code to grab the localStorage and send it to the React Native code, where I can work with it.

I'm using **react-native-webview**

**Here is the code**

1. Prepare JS for Injection to WebView to grab the localStorage

```
  const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(window?.localStorage || null));
  })();`;
```

2. Render some text to the user

```
  // Not required just to show something is happening 

  const customHTML = `
      <body style="background: #FCAD97">
           <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: center;justify-content: center;height: 100%;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;font-size: 3rem;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;display: table;color:white;">Syncing user data, please wait...</h1>
          </div>
       </body>`;
```

3. Actually get localStorage data from WebView

```
  function handleOnMessage(event) {
    // This will get the local storage in format {"localStorageKey": "localStorageValue"}
    const message = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);

   // Do something with the old local storage
  }
```

4. This is the most important part, we discovered, that cordova apps are running as **app://localhost** that's what you need to use as a baseUrl, if you use something else, the localStorage will be empty.

```
return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: customHTML, baseUrl: 'app://localhost' }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
        onMessage={handleOnMessage}
      />
    );
```

Once it's all done, you can just proceed to the app with the migrated localStorage data.

**The whole code looks like this:**

```
  const INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT = `(function() {
    window.ReactNativeWebView.postMessage(JSON.stringify(window?.localStorage || null));
  })();`;

  const customHTML = `
      <body style="background: #FCAD97">
           <div style="display: flex;flex-direction: row;align-items: center;justify-content: center;height: 100%;">
            <h1 style="text-align: center; margin-top: 20px;font-size: 3rem;font-family: Arial, sans-serif;display: table;color:white;">Syncing user data, please wait...</h1>
          </div>
       </body>`;

  function handleOnMessage(event) {
    // This will get the local storage in format {"localStorageKey": "localStorageValue"}
    const message = JSON.parse(event.nativeEvent.data);

   // Do something with the old local storage
  }

return (
      <WebView
        originWhitelist={['*']}
        source={{ html: customHTML, baseUrl: 'app://localhost' }}
        javaScriptEnabled={true}
        injectedJavaScript={INJECTED_JAVASCRIPT}
        onMessage={handleOnMessage}
      />
    );
```